# My teacher wants me to only use functions its not working for some reason its not working

Tags: python, function

The "correctCount" isn't going up for some reason even though in the generate_question function it is defined but still refuses to go up
The "goAgain Function will always go off if there is no try function
It needs to be all functions
Any help would be truly appreciated

```
 import random
    
    questionCount = 0
    correctCount = 0
    #defines the percent calculations into a single function
    def results_summary(correctCount, questionCount):
        percentage = correctCount / questionCount * 100
        correctCount = str(correctCount)
        questionCount = str(questionCount)
        percentage = str(round(percentage))
        print('You got ' + correctCount + '/' + questionCount + ' (' + percentage + '%).')
    
    #generates a question
    def generate_question(correctCount, questionCount):
        first = random.randint(1, 12)
        second = random.randint(1, 12)
        first = str(first)
        second = str(second)
        test = int(input('What is ' + first + ' x ' + second + '?\n'))
        second = int(second)
        first = int(first)
        if test == second * first:
            print('correct')
            correctCount += 1
        if test != second * first:
            print('incorrect')
        return correctCount
        enter code here
    
    #this function is used if the user enters a string
    def get_answer():
        print('Please only enter integers')
    
    #defines the repeating question into a single function
    def goAgain():
        while True:
            again = input('Would you like anouther question? (y / n)\n')
            if again == 'y':
                generate_question(correctCount, questionCount)
            if again == 'n':
                results_summary(correctCount, questionCount)
            break
    
    #MAIN PROGRAM
    generate_question(correctCount, questionCount)
    questionCount += 1
    while True:
        try:
            goAgain()
            questionCount += 1
        except ValueError:
            get_answer()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost correct, but you mixed global and local variables.
To keep track of the variables I favor local variables over global variables. When your code grows in length it can be hard to keep track of global variables and to reuse functions.

What this means is that you have to input AND return values. This is the only thing I changed in your code.

For example in `generate_question` you give the `correctCount` as input, but never returned. This is changed to use the input both `correctCount` and `questionCount` and the function returns those values. When calling the function you should thus save those since the function returns them. The next time the function is called you can again input those variables.

Like this: `questionCount, correctCount = generate_question(correctCount, questionCount)`.

I hope that this clears it up for you what went wrong in your code.

```
import random
   
#defines the percent calculations into a single function
def results_summary(correctCount, questionCount):
    percentage = correctCount / questionCount * 100
    print(f'You got {correctCount} /  {questionCount}  ( {percentage:.2f} %).')

#generates a question
def generate_question(correctCount, questionCount):
    # Add 1 to questioncount. 
    questionCount += 1
    first = random.randint(1, 12)
    second = random.randint(1, 12)
    # use f string to be able to use all variables. 
    test = int(input(f'What is {first}  x {second} ?\n'))
    if test == second * first:
        print('correct')
        correctCount += 1
    else:
        print('incorrect')
    return correctCount, questionCount

#this function is used if the user enters a string
def get_answer():
    print('Please only enter integers')

#defines the repeating question into a single function
def goAgain(correctCount, questionCount):
    again = input('Would you like anouther question? (y / n)\n')
    if again == 'y':
        correctCount, questionCount = generate_question(correctCount, questionCount)
        return True, correctCount, questionCount
    if again == 'n':
        results_summary(correctCount, questionCount)
        return False, None, None

#MAIN PROGRAM
questionCount = 0
correctCount = 0
correctCount, questionCount = generate_question(correctCount, questionCount)
while True:
    try:
        again, correctCount, questionCount = goAgain(correctCount, questionCount)
        if not again:
            break
    except ValueError:
        get_answer()
```

Comment: thank you so much but im kinda confused on what
test = int(input(f'What is {first}  x {second} ?\n'))
the f' and the { } was never taught to me

Comment: That is another way to format strings in combination with variables, see https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/.